# Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::getProducts(Array

Tags: magento-1.9, error, blocks, methods

I am trying to call getProducts method from content.phtml file.

Block file:

```
class AdminModules_Topjob_Block_Topjob extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
   {
        public function getProducts($pro_cond, $terminal_block)
        {
           $model = Mage::getModel('topjob/topjob');
           return $model->getProductsByCond($pro_cond, $terminal_block);
        }
   }
```

Content.phtml :

```
$myProducts = $this->getProducts('24 - 16 AWG', '2-CONDUCTOR TERMINAL BLOCKS');
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.1">
    <topjob_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="topjob/content" name="topjob" template="topjob/content.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </topjob_index_index>
</layout>
```

Error:

```
Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::getProducts(Array
(
    [0] => 24 - 16 AWG
    [1] => 2-CONDUCTOR TERMINAL BLOCKS
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/usauto/public_html/app/design/frontend/b-responsive/default/template/topjob/content.phtml(90): Varien_Object->__call('getProducts', Array)
#1 /home/usauto/public_html/app/design/frontend/b-responsive/default/template/topjob/content.phtml(90): Mage_Core_Block_Template->getProducts('24 - 16 AWG', '2-CONDUCTOR TER...')
#2 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/usauto/pu...')
#3 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/b-resp...')
#4 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 /home/usauto/public_html/app/design/frontend/b-responsive/default/template/page/1column.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/usauto/pu...')
#12 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/b-resp...')
#13 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/local/AdminModules/Topjob/controllers/IndexController.php(16): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): AdminModules_Topjob_IndexController->indexAction()
#19 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#20 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/usauto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/usauto/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/usauto/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file I would do :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.1">
    <topjob_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminmodules_topjob/topjob" name="topjob" template="topjob/content.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </topjob_index_index>
</layout>
```

Then flush your cache.
My guess is that your block type is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<block type="topjob/content" name="topjob" template="topjob/content.phtml" />
```

It should be

```
<block type="topjob/topjob" name="topjob" template="topjob/content.phtml" />
```

and your config.xml should have this under the `<global>` tag

```
<blocks>
     <topjob>
        <class>AdminModules_Topjob_Block</class>
     </topjob>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, <blocks> tag is there under <global> tag.  Also tried changing the block type, still not working